# Complicated button sprite

Tags: css, button, styling, css-sprites

I have this sprite:

[Link http://gpanel.darrell.nl/images/derma.png](http://gpanel.darrell.nl/images/derma.png)

And in the right upper corner there are 4 button images. I like to use the buttons like that the corners stay intact but that the rest can be stretched. I searched the whole internet but couldn't find a thing. How can I make this possible with CSS?

The same for the windows frame upper left.

Comment: Have you considered... not using the sprite? You could style the buttons with plain CSS.

Comment: What is a rectangle? A slice of a square with the left edge, followed by another slice repeated and then capped with a final slice with the right edge. I'm not sure however if that is the best solution to use in this case.

Comment: The idea behind it is that people can upload their own sprite with the same format to add their own style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately border-image doesn't work well with sprites, It can be done, but requires an extra element and some not-very-elegant tricks, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/H2xgQ/1/

```
.border{
    border-right: 400px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 400px solid black;
    border-image: url('http://gpanel.darrell.nl/images/derma.png') 3 388 388 3 fill stretch stretch;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
}
```